# I2C pins of nRF52832 Sparkfun breakout board require pull-up resistors?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, i2c, nrf52

I am trying to use press buttons via I2C using nRF52832 Sparkfun breakout board. I followed the steps given in [nrf52832-breakout-board-hookup-guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/nrf52832-breakout-board-hookup-guide/discuss) and changed the I2C Data and CLK pins to 24 and 25, respectively. I connected these pins and GND of the board to the corresponding pins and scanned for I2C devices. But it gave error = 2 (no I2C device) for all addresses. Should I use pull-up resistors? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I also used wire.h library. Should I use wire_nrf52? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes pull-up resistors on both SCL and SDA MUST be provided for I2C communication. Please see the following links:-

- [Infocenter specification](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.nrf52810.ps%2Ftwim.html&resultof=%22resistors%22%20%22resistor%22%20%22TWI%22%20%22twi%22%20) (See very end of section)
- [Devzone Question 1](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/40640/problem-with-communication-with-hts221-sensor/157991#157991)
- [DevZone Question 2](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/19425/by-default-internal-pull-up-resistors-for-twi-scl-sda-pins/75455#75455)
- [DevZone Question 3](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/16053/i2c-and-nrf52832/61213#61213)

I also recommend asking similar questions on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or directly on the [Nordic DevZone](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/) as there is higher chance of this being answered quicker.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I think it depends on the I2C device that we are using. This module has internal pull-up resistors, but it may not be enough for some devices. So, I disabled the internal pull-ups by replacing GPIO_PIN_CNF_PULL_Pullup with GPIO_PIN_CNF_PULL_Disabled for both SDA and SCL pins in the library and used external ones.